# Move turtles to vacant patch ahead in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm struggling to work out how to tell my turtles to move forward 1 onto a vacant patch, once they have already been turned around in a procedure called "turn-turtle".

```
     let ahead patch-ahead 1
     let vacant-ahead ahead  with [not any? turtles-here ] ;;this line needs fixing 
      if any? turtles      
                   [turn-turtle if vacant-ahead [fd 1]]
```

It produces this error, which I understand, but can't work out how to fix.

```
WITH expected input to be an agentset but got the patch (patch 1 -2) instead.
error while solute 2 running WITH
  called by procedure MOVE-TURTLE
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'
```

Just replying to some comments in a more readable fashion:
Sorry I don't think I explained it very well, as I've just taken a tiny bit of my code out. Maybe this makes more sense.

```
to go 
ask turtles 
[move-turtle] 
end 

to move-turtle 
turn-turtle 
if (not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1) 
[fd 1] 
end
```

So I just want this code to move the turtles that have been turned with "turn-turtle" to an empty patch ahead 1, preferably taking up the entire patch, like if they were "sprouted". Thanks!

Comment: What would you like to happen if the patch ahead is not vacant?

Comment: basically the error says that you can not use "with" on a single patch. In your code you're defining the variable "ahead" as a single patch (the patch-ahead 1) and then you're trying to use "with" on it to define the variable "vacant-ahead". This is not possible because you cannot make a subset of something that is not a set. It's not clear which is the purpose of your code: what exactly a turtle has to do?

Comment: Basically in words I just want the turtle that has been turned to move forward 1 into a vacant position. If it's not vacant it does nothing. I tried using  'and' instead for e.g.  'let vacant-ahead (ahead) and (not any? turtles-here)' but that doesn't help either.

Comment: I do not understand.  Your edit basically uses my answer but makes turning unconditional. Is there still a problem, or did my answer give you basically what you needed?  If there is still a problem, what is it?

Comment: I think there is still a problem, the edited code I added similar to yours now makes them move ok but the turtles are going on top of each other still, not in a volume exclusive manner. I want all the turtles to turn. My main problem is getting them to move forward onto a vacant patch and not overlap one another. P.s. sorry if its a bit confusing! NetLogo code is confusing for me!

Comment: Actually I had it set to clear all the values at the end of the move procedure which I don't think I needed, so got rid of that and they are moving volume exclusively now I think, thanks so much! @Alan

Comment: If you want your turtles to occupy the center of the patch, you can use `move-to patch-ahead 1` instead of `fd 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do something a bit different, if you really want `ahead` to be a single patch.  So perhaps

```
to move
  ifelse (any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1) [
    turn-turtle
  ][
    fd 1
  ]
end
```

Comment: Refer to my edits in the main text, thanks for trying though!